# Struts 2 autocomplete onchange not working

Tags: jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery

I am using js autocompleter tag in my application. My problem is that when I want to use the `onchange()` function in the tag it doesn't work. The `onchange()` function is not firing. How do I solve this issue?

My JSP

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function change_origin_state() {
    alert("in autocompleter onchange"); 
    return true; 
  }
</script> 

<s:autocompleter list="al_state_nm" 
                 name="orgState" 
                 listValue="state_nm" 
                 listKey="state_cd" 
                 cssStyle="width:180px;height:20px" 
                 onchange="return change_origin_state();"
/>
```

Comment: Can you show ur code?what the issue thrown

Comment: Yes, please edit your question and provide us a bit of your code so that we can try to see where the issue lies.

Comment: code will help us to understand your question? are you using simlple `js` or using `struts2-jquery` plugin?

Comment: <s:autocompleter list="al_state_nm" name="orgState" listValue="state_nm" listKey="state_cd" cssStyle="width:180px;height:20px" onchange="return change_origin_state();"/>     But the onchange() function is not working.

Comment: PLease provide .. JAAVSCRIPT code also .. Providing Code here is free of cost in SO please provide code ..

Comment: My javascript code is  <script type="text/javascript">      function change_origin_state()
        {
           alert("in autocompleter onchange"); return true;
        }</script> but i cannot see any alert in onchange.

Comment: Don't put code into comments, edit your question instead.

Comment: When do you expect `onchange` will be triggered for autocompleter?

Comment: When i change the sate names in the autocompleter box then the onchage() function will be triggered. But it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use onchange attribute when using the the autocompleter tag. A better approch is to use [autocompleter topics](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/AutocompleterTag#Topics) instead. They wrap the events from the [jQuery Ui autocompleter event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change)s.

You can find some example, like the one bellow, how to use this topics in the [Struts2 jQuery Showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action).

**JavaScript Code:**

```
$.subscribe('autocompleteChange', function(event, data) {
    var ui = event.originalEvent.ui;
    var message = ui.item.value;
    if(ui.item.key) {
        message = '( '+ ui.item.key +' ) '+message;
    }
    $('#topics').html('<b>'+message+'</b>');
});
$.subscribe('autocompleteFocus', function(event, data) {
    var ui = event.originalEvent.ui;
    var message = ui.item.value;
    if(ui.item.key) {
        message = '( '+ ui.item.key +' ) '+message;
    }
        $('#topics').html('<u>'+message+'</u>');
});

$.subscribe('autocompleteSelect', function(event, data) {
    var ui = event.originalEvent.ui;
    var message = ui.item.value;
    if(ui.item.key) {
        message = '( '+ ui.item.key +' ) '+message;
    }
        $('#topics').html('<i>'+message+'</i>');
});
```

**Code in JSP:**

```
<div id="topics" class="result ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div>
<s:url id="jsonlanguages" action="jsonlanguages"/> 
<sj:autocompleter 
            id="languages" 
            name="echo"
            label="Handle a Array"
            href="%{jsonlanguages}" 
            delay="50" 
            loadMinimumCount="2"
            onChangeTopics="autocompleteChange"
            onFocusTopics="autocompleteFocus"
            onSelectTopics="autocompleteSelect"
/>
```